# WF EtwTrackingParticipant Tracking variables

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have a workflow that that is using the EtwTrackingParticipant to track activities. When I open the tracked events in AppFabric Dashboard, it shows tracked variable names, but it doesn't show any value.

I am guessing it needs some kind of serialization help for those values.

Most of my variables are CLR types; do all of them have to be serializable to show up in the dashboard?

Comment: I added the WF4 tag, as EtwTrackingParticipant is listed as .NET 4. If that's incorrect please revise.